# Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop crash only in production

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My android app crash when trying to load data from firebase realtime database. This crash only happen in play store production.
I have tried building release apk and install in device it worked.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in
> Firebase Database runloop (19.6.0).  If you are not already on the
> latest version of the Firebase SDKs, try updating your dependencies.
> Should this problem persist, please file a report at
> https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk
>
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform$1$1.run(AndroidPlatform.java:6)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java) at
> com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)

AND

> Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
> object()Lk/a/e; in class Lk/a/e; or its super classes (declaration of
> 'k.a.e' appears in
> /data/app/com.example.android.buyer-zyr2oysT1mAsYofRhpiDMA==/base.apk)
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper.serializeJsonValue(JsonMapper.java:4)
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper.serializeJsonValue(JsonMapper.java:59)
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper.serializeJson(JsonMapper.java:12)
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.send(WebsocketConnection.java:12)
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.sendData(Connection.java:12)
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.sendRequest(Connection.java:12)
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.sendSensitive(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:12)
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.sendAction(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:22)
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onConnectionReady(Connection.java:22)
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onHandshake(Connection.java:22)
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onControlMessage(Connection.java:2)
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.g(Connection.java:47)
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.appendFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:6)
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:4)
> at
> com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock$2.run(WebsocketConnection.java:4)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)

This is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.afrimarketsquare.android.buyer"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 35
        versionName "2.3.5"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('/Users/pc/Desktop/me/path/to/key.keystore')
            storePassword '..djjd'
            keyPassword '..dhd'
            keyAlias = '..dhdh'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == "androidx.appcompat") {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion "1.+"
                    //details.useVersion "${targetSdk}.+"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"

    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.35.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.fenchtose.nocropper:nocropper:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar"
    implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.5.0'
    implementation 'co.paystack.android:paystack:3.0.18'
    implementation 'io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:3.1.2'
    implementation 'com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.9.1'
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0'
}
```

Below is my code to query firebase

```
public void loadNotificationDatabase(NotificationsActivity.dataFinishChanging myCallback) {
    ArrayList<NotificationsHandler> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    Query ref = notificationDatabase.child(user.getKey()).orderByChild("notification_time").limitToLast(100);

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                NotificationsHandler list = dataSnapshot.getValue(NotificationsHandler.class);
                if (list != null) {
                    list.setTitle(ds.child("notification_title").getValue(String.class));
                    list.setMessage(ds.child("notification_message").getValue(String.class));
                    list.setUserid(ds.child("notification_to").getValue(String.class));
                    list.setType(ds.child("notification_type").getValue(String.class));
                    list.setImage(ds.child("notification_image").getValue(String.class));
                    list.setFrom(ds.child("notification_from").getValue(String.class));
                    list.setStatus(ds.child("notification_status").getValue(String.class));
                    list.setRowKey(ds.child("notification_id").getValue(String.class));
                    Long time = ds.child("notification_time").getValue(long.class);
                    if(time != null) {
                        list.setTimestamp(time);
                    }else{
                        list.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
                    }
                }
                lists.add(list);
            }
            Collections.reverse(lists);
            myCallback.onCallback(lists);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.e("FB", "Error: " + error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried updating your dependencies on the latest version, as the error message says?

Comment: @AlexMamo I just chang from `firebase-bom:26.4.0` to `firebase-bom:26.6.0`. but is there any way can test the fix without releasing my app?

Comment: Yes, on the local emulator, or real device.

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes that what I was using but it doesn't crash except when I download from play store

Comment: Are you suing ProGurad to obfuscate the data?

Comment: @AlexMamo no rule in my `proguard`. Even after I have updated the latest firebase version and upload my app in play store it still crash.